# sp_tables with argument @table_type doesn't return anything

Tags: sql-server

Based on [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-tables-transact-sql) for `sp_tables`, I can run something like this below:

```
exec sp_tables
   @table_name = '%',  
   @table_owner = 'dbo',  
   @table_qualifier = 'my_db';
```

and I should get an expected result like this:

```
TABLE_QUALIFIER   TABLE_OWNER   TABLE_NAME   TABLE_TYPE  REMARKS
-----------------------------------------------------------------
my_db             dbo           table1       TABLE       NULL
my_db             dbo           table2       TABLE       NULL
my_db             dbo           view1        VIEW        NULL
```

But when I try this:

```
exec sp_tables
   @table_name = '%',  
   @table_owner = 'dbo',  
   @table_qualifier = 'my_db',
   @table_type = 'TABLE';
```

it returns nothing.

Does this mean I cannot use `@table_type` to filter just the views or tables using `sp_tables`? I use Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) - 11.0.7001.0 (X64) if that matters.

Thank you in advanced for answers/suggestions!

Comment: `@table_type = "'TABLE'"` - "*Single quotation marks must enclose each **table type**, and double quotation marks must enclose the **whole parameter**.*"

Comment: @PM 77-1 Thank you! Adding single quote fixes the issue. :)